# Encapsulate the properties file for a class is a good practice?

Tags: java, python

In other languages such as Python it is possible to perform logic in the configuration files and Java this is not allowed because it is a compiled language.

I decided to encapsulate the settings of .properties file into a Java object, thus have the advantage of being able to validate the file information, generate logic and even use the autocomplete Eclipse but have the disadvantage of not being able to dynamically create properties, so I doubt if this is a good practice or just something to complicate the development more.

Ex:

File config.properties

```
email.user=user
email.host=smtp.email.com
email.auth=true
```

Java class:

```
public class Config {

    private String emailUser;
    private String emailHost;
    private Boolean emailAuth;

    public Config() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(Config.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
            emailUser = properties.getProperty("email.user");
            emailHost = properties.getProperty("email.host");
            emailAuth = Boolean.valueOf(properties.getProperty("email.auth"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Only Gets

}
```

Comment: That's how we do it. All the validation logic goes in a config class, and the rest of the application doesn't care how the properties get loaded.  This makes it easy to (for instance) read your properties from a database instead of a flat file, since you only need to modify the one Config class.

Comment: We don't worry about having to touch the code to add properties, since we'd have to touch the code to add the logic to use those properties, anyway.

Comment: Make your private member `final`.